# Why I get different date formats when I run my application through IIS and Visual Studio's web server on the same computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get the same culture i.e. "en-US" while running the website from both IIS and Visual Studio's web server.

But I get a different date format as follows, when I run the following code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

On Visual Studio's web server: dd/MM/yyyy en-US

On IIS: M/d/yyyy en-US

Does "Regional and Language Options" in "Control Panel" play any role in this ?
If I change the date format there in "Regional and Language Options", I see no effect in my application.

Comment: sounds like this are server formats
maybe you can change that in IIS propertys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IIS server (or rather the ASP.NET worker process) is running under a different account, while the VS web server is running under your user account. `Thread.CurrentCulture` gets the current culture for the user account the thread is executing as.

Comment: That means, changing the date format through "Control Panel->Regional and Language Options" should change the format while running through VS web server, because it will pick up the culture from there. Am I right ? But this is not happening.

Comment: Did you restart the dev server after you changed the date format in Control panel?

Comment: Yes, I didn't restart the dev server. Thanks!!